# upgrade to NHibernate 3.0.0.1002, Table is not mapped

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, exception, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-3

Yesterday, I upgraded my NHibernate application from 1.2 to 3.0. I get the following exception

```
c.SubContractors is not mapped [SELECT count(distinct c) FROM CallUp c, c.SubContractors sc Where sc.id = :id AND c.ChildCallUp IS NULL AND c.State > 0 AND (:start_date BETWEEN c.ContractStartDate AND c.ContractEndDate OR :end_date BETWEEN c.ContractStartDate AND c.ContractEndDate)]
```

I can't seem to fix this problem... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HQL syntax is incorrect. Use:

```
SELECT count(distinct c) 
FROM CallUp c JOIN c.SubContractors sc 
WHERE sc.id = :id 
AND c.ChildCallUp IS NULL 
AND c.State > 0 
AND (:start_date BETWEEN c.ContractStartDate AND c.ContractEndDate 
     OR :end_date BETWEEN c.ContractStartDate AND c.ContractEndDate)
```

Comment: Yes, You are right! Replaced the comma with JOIN Everything worked. I guess the syntax has changed since NHibernate 3

Comment: Actually, the changed probably happened in NH 2.x